# 'MEMORY_OPTIMIZED' is not a recognized CREATE TYPE option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm experimenting with [memory-optimized user-defined table types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization) (§D.2 and §E) on SQL Server 2016.

Context:

- SQL Server Enterprise 13.0.4446.0 (that's CU4, released August 8, 2017)
- Database restored from a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance
- Database's `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` set to 130 (SQL Server 2016)
- Created a memory optimized filegroup for database

And yet:

```
create type dbo.test_type as table(
id int not null,
primary key clustered (id asc) 
    with (ignore_dup_key = off, memory_optimized = on))
```

fails with output:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 'memory_optimized' is not a
>   recognized CREATE TYPE option.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: @Siyual the version of SSMS isn’t relevant, this is a run time error being returned from the server not an intellisense error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this.

`memory_optimized` is a property of the type not the primary key.

```
create type dbo.test_type as table(
id int not null,
primary key nonclustered (Id))
With (memory_optimized = on)
```

Comment: Additionally:The index option 'ignore_dup_key' is not supported with indexes on memory optimized tables.
Clustered indexes, which are the default for primary keys, are not supported with memory optimized tables. Specify a NONCLUSTERED index instead.